Car parking - quant guide
Suppose that we have 2 cars parked in a line occupying spaces 1 and 2 of a parking lot. Spaces 3 and 4 are initially empty. Every minute, a car is considered eligible to move forward one space if
a) the space in front of them is empty prior to any potential moves and
b) label of the space they are on is less than 4. Suppose that every minute, if a car is eligible to move, it moves forward one space with probability 1/2.
What is the expected amount of minutes before the cars occupy spaces 3 to 4?
Note: The space in front must be empty before any moves. For example, on the first turn, only the car in space 2 is eligible to move.
I have solved it using case by case after every minute. I got the answer and it is 20/3.(Writing the possible positions of two cars after one minute and writing the expected value of initial positions of car in terms of the expected values of new state of cars).However my solution look tedious. I am looking for another solution. Any idea would be appreciated.Thanks.
Note : this problem is in the quant guide website- https://www.quantguide.io/questions/car-question-i

Just to clarify: (1) We're only considering these two cars. No other cars are arriving to park? And (2) Space number 4 is the frontmost space and space number 1 the rearmost?

@paw88789 we are only considering these two cars. 2)cars are moving from lower number to higher number

I'd do it with states.  Label a state by the occupied spaces, so you start in $S_{1,2}$ and seek to achieve $S_{3,4}$.  Set up a (simple) system of linear equations for the expectations, and solve.

By the method of @lulu your answer is correct.

For $1 \le i < j \le 4$, let $(i,j)$ be the situation where the cars are in spaces $i$ and $j$.
During the process described in the problem, we will definitely be in the states $(1,2)$, $(1,3)$, $(2,4)$, and $(3,4)$. We may or may not be in one (and only one) of the states $(1, 4)$ and $(2,3)$.
On average, it takes two minutes to get from the initial state $(1,2)$ to $(1,3)$.
From $(1,3)$, in any given minute, there is a $\frac34$ probability of leaving that state. So, on average, it takes $\frac43$ minutes to leave state $(1,3)$.
The next (new) state after $(1,3)$ is equally likely to be any of $(1,4)$, $(2,3)$, or $(2,4)$. From either of states $(1,4)$ or $(2,3)$, the next (new) state will be $(2,4)$, which will take an average of $2$ minutes to get to. Of course if our next new state after $(1,3)$ is $(2,4)$, then there are $0$ additional minutes after leaving $(1,3)$ to get to $(2,4)$.
So, getting from state $(1,3)$ to state $(2,4)$, on average will take $\frac43+\frac23\cdot 2+\frac13\cdot 0=\frac{8}{3}$ minutes.
And getting from state $(2,4)$ to state $(3,4)$ will take an average of $2$ minutes.
Putting this all together gives an expected total time of $2+\frac83+2=\frac{20}{3}$ minutes to get from state $(1,2)$ to state $(3,4)$.
